# Перенаправление данных http

Tags: iptables, http, linux

Возможно не правильно озаглавил вопрос.
Суть проблемы:
в локальной сети есть IP камеры с локальными адресами из диапазона 192.168.0.0;
есть сервер (Ubuntu Server), с двумя интерфейсами - один локальный в этой же подсети, другой в интеренет смотрит.
Камеры по HTTP выдают картинку.
На сервере также поднят сайт. Собственно на этом сайте должны быть картинки с камер.
Разместить картинки из потока не проблема. Вопрос как быть с адресами камер?

Если же использовать ссылки на поток

```
http://admin@192.168.0.25/image/jpeg.cgi
```

получится ерунда, т.к. адрес локальный.

Comment: Может быть портфорвардинг через iptables  и разные порты для каждой камеры на внешнем интерфейсе?

Answer (score 1):

Так у вас есть внешний адрес, сделайте скрипт, который будет парсить запрос извне, например `http://external_ip(host)/25`, и выдавать на него картинку с камеры (так как сервер знает обе сети, он сможет загрузить себе картинку и передать ее во внешку). Можно еще помудрить с `.htaccess (mod_rewrite)` чтобы он передавал уже нужную ссылку скрипту, а скрипт будет только заниматься получением картинки.

Второй вариант - настроить http-сервер в режим прокси и указать ему на нужные ресурсы, но этот вариант почти не отличается от первого: просто разными "инстанциями" будет разбираться ссылка.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял то вам нужно использовать NAT.
192.168.0.25 - это адрес одной из камер?

Comment: Да, это адрес камеры.
Насколько я понимаю, NAT не подходит - снаружи будет виден только один адрес с одним 80-м портом. И как понять где какая камера неясно.

Answer (score 0):

Подходит,ваша ссылка просто примет вид:
    http://admin@внешний*ip*сервака:порт/image/jpeg.cgi
Порт будет задаваться при помощи NAT

Comment: Тогда уж портфорвардинг